# C# FTP File from Object

Tags: c#, ftp

I am trying to create an XML file from an object and save it to an FTP. My code successfully creates the file in the FTP, but the file just says NULL. PORequest is my object. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
        static void FTPXmlFile(PORequest req, string fileNameToCreate, string ftpUrl, string ftpPassword, string ftpUserName)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream = SerializeToStream(req);
        // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpUrl + fileNameToCreate);
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        // This example assumes the FTP site uses anonymous logon.
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserName, ftpPassword);
        request.UseBinary = false;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[memoryStream.Length];

        memoryStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        memoryStream.Close();

        using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            reqStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }


        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        response.Close();
    }

    static MemoryStream SerializeToStream(object o)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, o);
        return stream;
    }
```

Update:

Here is the code that worked:

```
        static MemoryStream GetMemoryStream(object req)
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(req.GetType());
        string s = null;
        using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, req);
            s = textWriter.ToString();
        }

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
        writer.Write(s);
        writer.Flush();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        return memoryStream;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like a Unicode/ASCII conversion problem (since most "normal" Unicode characters start with a null)

Comment: Thanks! I changed my object into a  string and it worked.